Дискретные переменные Scratch
Пишу компилятор для Scratch 3. В файле проекта, в "monitors" среди параметров переменной нсшёл "isdescrete". Хочу понять, как в Scratch можно создать не дескретную переменную.
Я сначала пытался менять значение самой переменной в онлайн-редакторе. Потом изменил этот параметр вручную в файле проекта, открыл в редакторе, никаких видимых изменений не появилось.
